# Select value from dropdown with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a value from a dropdown with selenium webdriver but it just opens the dropdown and immediately closes it.

Here is the code for webdriver:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.k-select  ")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='k-item'][.='Revenue per click']")).click();
```

And this is the html code from the browser for the dropdown:

```
<div class="controls">  
    <span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header kendo-input span8 ddFix" unselectable="on">
      <span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
         <span unselectable="on" class="k-input">Select revenue type...
         </span>
         <span unselectable="on" class="k-select">
            <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span>
         </span>
       </span>
      <input name="revenueType" id="revenueType" class="kendo-input span8 ddFix" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;">
  </span>
</div>

 <div class="k-animation-container km-popup">
      <div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="revenueType-list" data-role="popup">
          <ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" id="revenueType_listbox" aria-live="off" style="overflow: auto;">
              <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">Select revenue type...</li>
              <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">Revenue per action</li>
              <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">Revenue per click</li>
              <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">Revenue per sale</li>
              <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">Revenue per action + Revenue per sale</li>
              <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">Revenue per mile</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is the drop down

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug without the context but:

1. Your locator is invalid, instead try using:

   ```
   By.xpath("//li[text()='Revenue per click']")
   ```

   Since only one item has that text, it should be sufficient. If you still want to include `@class` in selector, use

   ```
   By.xpath("//li[@class='k-item' and text()='Revenue per click']")
   ```
2. Try using javascript change the unselectable to off using javascript executor.

Comment: it still doesn't work, as i can see the main problem is that after it click on dropdown it opens and immediately close and this second line doesn't have time to find this text that i want to select, i've tried to put Thread.sleep(3000) after first click but it does not help

Answer (score 0):

**Get the dropdown text value after perform click action**

```
subdropdown_child = navigationDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("select#ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c873566a_540c_4681 option");                                 
for (Element subchild : subdropdown_child) 
  {    
     dropdown_value = subchild.text();
     new Select(navigationDriver.findElementByCssSelector("select#ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c873566a_540c_4681_")).selectByVisibleText(dropdown_value);
  }
```